# Solving $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\Big[\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{m}-1\Big]$ without l'Hôpital.

Tags: limits

Using l'Hôpital's rule we can easily see the limit is $m$. I'm wondering whether there is any other way of solving the limit withOUT using l'Hôpital's.

EDIT: I'm avoiding l'Hôpital because I encountered the limit in a point of the book where the author has not yet introduced that topic, and I'm trying to figure out what he had in mind for solving this limit. So far the chapters have been an introductory one (properties of real numbers, set theory, etc...), a chapter for sequences, and series. I'm solving the limit as part of the Raabe criterion for series.

Comment: Binomial expansion of $(1+\frac  1 n)^{m}$ makes this obvious.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I thought about this for natural numbers, but what about for rational $m$?

Comment: $(1+\frac 1 n)^{m}-1=\frac m n (1+x)^{m-1}$ for some $x$ between $1$ and $1+\frac  1n$ by MVT.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy While I appreciate your answer, MVT has not yet been discussed by the author in the section of the book in which the limit was encountered. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @alexd Happy New Year Alex! I hope you're staying safe and doing well during the pandemic. I've reached out a couple of times, but am unsure whether you've received the messages. So, if you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that use of Bernoulli's Inequality reveals for $n>1$

$$\frac mn\le \left(1+\frac1n\right)^m-1\le \frac{m/n}{1-\frac mn}$$

And you can finish now.

Comment: How did you obtain the RHS of the inequality?

Comment: Hi Alex.  For $n> 1$ we have $$\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^m \le 1\implies \left(1+\frac1n\right)^m \le \frac1{ \left(1-\frac1n\right)^m }\le \frac1{1-\frac mn}$$

Comment: @alexd Happy New Year Alex! I hope you're staying safe and doing well during the pandemic. I've reached out a couple of times, but am unsure whether you've received the messages. So, if you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Do a variable substitution:

$x=1+\frac{1}{n}$

$n=\frac{1}{x-1}$

So the limit becomes

$$\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}\frac{x^m-1}{x-1}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}(x^{m-1}+x^{m-2}+...1)$$

$$=m$$

Comment: (+1) I like this approach

Comment: +1 Elegant answer.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding $(1+\frac{1}{n})^m$ using binomial theorem we get the limit.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n((1+1/n)^m-1) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^m {m \choose i}\frac{1}{n^i}\biggr)=m
\end{align*}

Comment: I thought about this for natural numbers, but what about for rational $m$?

Comment: @Alex: the binomial theorem holds for all $m$ (real or even complex), although then the sum will be infinite and the definition of ${m \choose i}$ needs to be generalized. You will need to estimate the error in truncating the sum but this is doable.

Comment: @nrynn Even simpler is application of Bernoulli's Inequality.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes indeed.+1 for your answer.

Comment: @AlexD I wrongly assumed $m$ to be a natural number. Please see Mark's nice solution.